# Spark Streaming - reduceByKey for a Map inside DStream

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

How do I leverage reduceByKey in Spark / Spark Streaming for a normal Scala Map that resides inside DStream?

I have a `DStream[(String, Array[(String, List)])]` where I want to apply `reduceByKey` function to the inside `Array[(String, List)]` (joining all the lists together)

I am able to do this in normal Spark by converting the outside RDD to normal Array (to avoid serialization error on SparkContext object),

then run a foreach and apply `sc.parallelize()` to the inside `Array[(String, List)]`

But since DStream doesn't have any direct conversion to normal array I'm not able to apply `sc.parallelize()` to the inside component and hence no `reduceByKey` function.

I'm very new to Spark and Spark Streaming (the whole map-reduce concept actually) and this might not be the right way to do this so if anyone could advise a better practice please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question so hopefully you figured this out but....
in order to be able to perform reduceByKey... operations on a DStream you must first import StreamingContext:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
```

This provides implicit methods extending DStream. 
Once you've done this not only can you perform stock reduceByKey you can also use time sliced functions like:

```
reduceByKeyAndWindow((a: List, b: List) => (a ::: b), Seconds(30), Seconds(30))
```

These can be quite useful if you want to do aggregation within a sliding window.
Hope that helps!